# jQuery combobox error when initialized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, combobox

I have a problem. I will try add combobox to my select but i have error

```
TypeError: e(...).addClass(...).appendTo(...).menu(...) is .../include/jquery-ui-1.11.0.custom/jquery-ui.min.js
Line 9
```

I work with basic code from jquery autocomplete combobox. [code here](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox)

Comment: Add your code. This does not tell me much.

Comment: Try adding `option`s to your `select`

Answer (score 0):

Refer **[this DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/dzVgL/)** for creating a basic jquery-ui selectmenu (combobox)

JS code:

```
$(function() {

     $( "#combobox" ).selectmenu({
         change: function( event, ui ) {
             console.log(ui);
             var selected_value = ui.item.value;
             alert("You selected : "+selected_value);
         }
     });
});
```